# Can someone show me an example configuration for Emacs with lsp-mode working for Erlang?

Tags: emacs, erlang, language-server-protocol

I am currently looking through github configuration files to find a working example of lsp-mode and Erlang working together properly. Right now I am stuck with a broken configuration that errors out at the start:

```
Server erlang-ls:176779 status:starting exited with status exit. Do you want to restart it? (y or n) y
LSP :: Restarting LSP in buffer example.erl
LSP :: Sending to process failed with the following error: Process erlang-ls not running
LSP :: Connected to [erlang-ls:176780 status:starting].
LSP :: erlang-ls has exited (exited abnormally with code 127)
```

Here is my configuration so far:

```
(use-package lsp-mode
    :ensure t
    :hook ((erlang-mode . lsp)
           ;; if you want which-key integration
           (lsp-mode . lsp-enable-which-key-integration))
    :commands lsp
    :config
       (setq lsp-erlang-server-path "/home/yk42bb/from_source/erlang_ls/_build/default/bin/erlang_ls")
       (add-to-list 'exec-path "/home/yk42bb/from_source/erlang_ls/_build/default/bin"))
(use-package lsp-ui
     :ensure t
     :config
     (define-key lsp-ui-mode-map [remap xref-find-definitions] #'lsp-ui-peek-find-definitions)
     (define-key lsp-ui-mode-map [remap xref-find-references] #'lsp-ui-peek-find-references))
(use-package erlang
    :ensure t
    :mode "\\.erl\\'"
    :config (erlang-mode))
(use-package company-erlang
    :ensure t)
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the fault lay in exec-path-from-shell loading my zsh configuration in a buggy manner, because I didn't comment out the powerlevel9k/powerlevel10k prompt stuff with `[[ $TERM != "dumb" && ... ]]`.